# Ajax GET Parameter to MVC 5 Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering why my `ajax` call to my `Controller` works when my Parameter is called `id` and doesn't work when it's called `accountNo` or `accountId`.

### Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "json",
             cache: false,
             url: config.url.root + "/DeferredAccount/GetDeferredAccountDetailsByAccount/" + accountNo
                });
```

### Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetDeferredAccountDetailsByAccount(int id)
        {
            var details = _deferredAccountDetailsService.GetDeferredAccountDetailsByAccount(id);

            return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In my `Controller` - if the parameter is `int id` everything works.

[image]

If I change the `Controller` parameter to, let's say, `accountNum`, I receive a 500 error stating that my parameter is `null`.

[image]

So, it's literally just the naming of the Parameter for the Controller that dictates the success of my `GET` request or not. Is it because it's JSON encoded, and I'm not specifying the data model/format in my `ajax` method?

If an answer exists for this, I apologize as I haven't come across it.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the `RouteConfig.cs` by default defines the third component of your route as the variable `id`.

You can get to that controller by specifying the URL

`/DeferredAccount/GetDeferredAccountDetailsByAccount/?accountNum=1`

### Using attribute routing

There is another more fine-grained way of serving your routing with MVC 5 known as attribute routing.

**Edit `RouteConfig.cs`**
Add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

**Edit Controller**

```
[Route("/whatever/path/i/like/{accountNum:int}")]
public JsonResult GetDeferredAccountDetailsByAccount(int accountNum)
{
    [...]
}
```

[**MSDN**: Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)

Comment: Silly question, but since you're here :  I wouldn't need to have the Route Attr on every controller method would I?

Comment: RTM ;) - "You can also combine attribute routing with convention-based routing.".

Comment: Thanks - got it now. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

you may put below Route on top in your RouteConfig.cs file

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "DeferredAccount", action = "GetDeferredAccountDetailsByAccount", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```